# Pyspark error : py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, py4j

I'm using Python 3.6.7 and Pyspark 2.3.0 and spark 2.3.0 on a jupyter notebook to extract tweets from kafka and process them using spark streaming. On the running the following code :

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2 pyspark-shell'

from pyspark import SparkContext
#    Spark Streaming
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
#    Kafka
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
#    json parsing
import json
import logging

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSparkStreamingKafka_RM_01")
sc.setLogLevel("INFO")

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)

logging.getLogger("py4j").setLevel(logging.ERROR)

kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, 'cdh57-01-node-01.moffatt.me:2181', 'spark-streaming', {'kafkaspark':1})
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Sentiment_Analysis\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1062, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Sentiment_Analysis\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 908, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "C:\Sentiment_Analysis\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1067, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a7a877501187> in <module>
----> 1 kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, 'cdh57-01-node-01.moffatt.me:2181', 'spark-streaming', {'kafkaspark':1})

C:\Sentiment_Analysis\spark\python\pyspark\streaming\kafka.py in createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, groupId, topics, kafkaParams, storageLevel, keyDecoder, valueDecoder)
     77         jlevel = ssc._sc._getJavaStorageLevel(storageLevel)
     78         helper = KafkaUtils._get_helper(ssc._sc)
---> 79         jstream = helper.createStream(ssc._jssc, kafkaParams, topics, jlevel)
     80         ser = PairDeserializer(NoOpSerializer(), NoOpSerializer())
     81         stream = DStream(jstream, ssc, ser)

C:\Sentiment_Analysis\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1158         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1159         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1160             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1161 
   1162         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\Sentiment_Analysis\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326             raise Py4JError(
    327                 "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}".
--> 328                 format(target_id, ".", name))
    329     else:
    330         type = answer[1]

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o32.createStream
```

I'm clueless how to resolve this error ? I am beginner in Spark and kafka , so can someone please explain to me in simple words on how to get rid of this ? What should I do ?

Comment: You've connected to Zookeeper, not Kafka. You might also want to consider using Structured Streaming instead

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I have another producer code running on kafka. It is the consumer side using spark streaming that throws this error. I'm using the old version because there were many compatibility issues with the new structured streaming.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on connection to kafka ? I'm running the zookeeper , server , producer and consumer along with the kafka cluster program

Comment: Port 9092 should be connected to. You're using 2181

Comment: Changed it. I still get the same error.

Comment: What version of Java do you have installed?

Comment: I've installed java 1.8

Comment: Hmm. Okay, so next, you have your package Kafka version `2.0.2` but you need 2.3.0 to match your Spark version

Comment: Yes. Thanks . Resolved it . But I'm facing other problems . Anyways, this error is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a question of compatibility please to refer to this link : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#advanced-sources
So  to solve your issue use kafka libraries of a version compatible with your spark version.